# Sending and viewing user input strings to another activity on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am kinda new to Android programming and I have an issue. I'm looking forward to find out after hours of searching.
I basically have a program that at the first screen you enter your name and you press a button to go to the next activity.
Then on the next activity I want to print "Welcome (and the name user entered)" eg. Welcome John.
Until now I have figured out how to store the string on the first activity and sent it as an intent.extras() on the other. That works ok.
My problem is how can I now print it as a TextView or something that I can edit on xml too, so I can achieve what I said.

Code:
MainActivity.java (onClick)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Welcome.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
    });

}
```

Welcome.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) return;

    String name = extras.getString("name");


}
```

What I was thinking as a solution is that is there a way to add a new entry on strings.xml, or change the value of one already declared? Is there something easy I haven't already thought? Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a TextView in your layout and then in the Welcome activity you can edit the content like this:

```
welcomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcomeTextView );
welcomeTextView.setText("Welcome " + extras.getString("name"));
```